# Internationalising multiple frames java swing

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

I managed to internationalize my first frame the rsaMainMenu.java but I cannot figure out how to for example change language in all the other frames by pressing the button in the first frame rsaMainMenu.java.

**Here is the code in my rsaMainMenu.java**

```
static ResourceBundle r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.MyResourceBundle");
Locale locale;
Locale l = new Locale("en", "EN");
```

**Below is the code for the button taking the user to next frame**

```
private void previewSignActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    new rsaSignsPreviewCategory(l).setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```

**And here is 1 of 3 buttons to change the language in this case into German.**

```
private void languageDEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    l = new Locale("de", "DE");
    ResourceBundle r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles/myResourceBundle_de", l);

    exitButton.setText(r.getString("exitButton"));
    previewSign.setText(r.getString("preview_Signs"));
    mockTest.setText(r.getString("mock_test")); 
}
```

Here is my second frame, I was trying to figure it out but I finally decided to try and get some help.

```
static ResourceBundle r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.MyResourceBundle");
Locale l;
public rsaSignsPreviewCategory(Locale l) {
    initComponents();
    this.l = l;
}
```

Sorry if my issue is stupidly easy, I am new to programming and also stack overflow. If you have any tips
in terms of my post formatting please allow yourself for some constructive critique.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Oracle's [Internationalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/index.html)

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is. Since `r` is static in rsaMainMenu, you could access it using `rsaMainMenu.r.getString`, there is no need to reload the bundle. If `initComponents` already correcly loads all Strings from that bundle nothing else needs to be done. Also note `ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles/myResourceBundle_de", l)` is not needed, `ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles/myResourceBundle", l)` would suffice since the method automatically looks for the bundle named after the given locale.